# Providing a complex default value on table involved in Parallel DML

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a number of tables involved in a merge statement that is running parallel. The merge outputs to an error table which is generated via the DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG function. The statement works fine, and the merge works.

I then added an additional column to the error table, and it continues to work without issue.

I now wish to make that additional column have a default value based on a value elsewhere in the system (in essence the batch processing date, which is not the same as the current datetime in anyway) - and I am tripping up over restrictions at every turn.

- I tried populating the value using a trigger - but that then places a trigger on a table involved in parallel DML which is not permitted, and and error is thrown during the merge. (This does error annoyingly)
- I tried adding a default value based on a pl/sql function - this is not permitted.
- I tried adding a default value based on a sql statement - this is again not permitted.

I could implement an additional update post processing to populate the column, but this would then have to be done for every table that I merge and really is a bit of a hack - as the system expands this would have to be remembered for every error table. Populating the default value is the preferred approach.

How do I work around Oracles PDML restriction on the trigger to populate this value based on effectively a select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value sounds fairly static, look at SYS_CONTEXT.
For example, I have a logging table where I store the currently running module (set with DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO).

column_name    VARCHAR2(256) DEFAULT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE'),

Not sure whether a conventional context value is stored for the session or process. If it doesn't work for parallel processing, check out the [GLOBAL APPLICATION CONTEXT](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/network.101/b10773/apdvcntx.htm#1008733) which you can apply across all sessions for a given username

Comment: This probably has the best chance / innovative workaround to the limitations that exist.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a little bit outside the scope of what DML error tables are intended to do natively, and then yes - the parallel DML rules are going to retrict you from other options. The easiest way to resolve this would be to add that batch processing date to the original table so that it also is reflected in the error table. Costs you a bit of storage, but if you need to identify rows by batch anyway....

Or, as you mention, there is a post-process solution. Finally, is there perhaps a way to layer that information into a view that overlays the error table when you go to look at the errors? Or is the batch date impossible to calculate at a later time?

Comment: You don't need to add the date to the original table.  If you just want to add a literal value you can use the (simple_expression) part of the error_logging_clause, and it will insert that value into the column ORA_ERR_TAG$.

Comment: I only need to identify the error row by batch run - and I have considered including it but again this then requires manual adjustment of every merge and including it on an future merges etc. The date can not be reverse calculated and the table will hold multiple days values.

Comment: @jonearles - already using that column for other information, although that might have to be sacrificed off. Really should be able to just add a column and let it default to what I need except the PDML / Trigger then clashes